# Get first argument of wc -l myFile.txt

Tags: bash, wc

I'm counting the number of lines in a big file using

```
wc -l myFile.txt
```

Result is

```
110 myFile.txt
```

But I want only the number

```
110
```

How can I do that?
(I want the number of lines as an input argument in a bash script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here are two:

```
 wc -l myFile.txt | cut -f1 -d' '

 wc -l < myFile.txt
```

Cut is an old Unix tool to

> print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.

Comment: Glad to see someone using redirection rather than useless use of  `awk`

Comment: First command works! The second (non-tls) seems not to be correct: Where should I put "myFile.txt" in that case

Comment: @mcExchange That was a file I had on my system. I edited my answer a minute after posting when I realised my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` and pipe `wc -l`:

```
cat myFile.txt | wc -l
```

Or if you insist `wc -l` be the first command, you can use `awk`:

```
wc -l myFile.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Comment: Useless link ;) It's serving my needs (specially in logs) since ever.

Comment: Hoisted by my own petard!  http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
wc -l file | awk '{print $1}'
```